# Why uninitialized constant HomeController::HideMyAss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Using [hidemyass](https://github.com/jassa/hidemyass) gem for proxy.

Using github example code.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController        
  require 'hidemyass'   
  def index                 
    HideMyAss.options[:max_concurrency] = 3
    response = HideMyAss.get("www.google.com", timeout: 2)
  end   
end
```

Whey I try to use them in my rails controller, I get the Uninitialized constant error.

```
uninitialized constant HomeController::HideMyAss
```

Tried looking at the source to figure out with no luck. Maybe it's the problem with my code. Gemfile is good and tried looking at all the things causing the problem.

Comment: What if you try `::HideMyAss.options` ...?

Comment: Can you try ::HideMyAss.options[] and ::HideMyAss.get()

Comment: did you do 'bundle install'?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev doing so throws 'undefined method `options' for HideMyAss:Module' error.

Comment: @emaillenin bundle install, restarted server.

Comment: Did you try customizing this module by reopening it? That is, do have this line anywhere in your code: `module HideMyAss`?

Comment: No, I even tried this on a fresh rails 4.0 app. Could this be a possible bundler install issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to write `require 'hidemyass'`

You just need to add `gem 'hidemyass'` to Gemfile and do `bundle install`. Check installation with `gem list hidemyass` command. I have successfully checked it and used github example. It works fine and smoothly.

Comment: I got the following response

** [hidemyass] Connecting to www.google.com through:
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY url= response_code=0 return_code=recv_error total_time=0.839136
** [hidemyass] http://58.221.29.68:7070 : 0
ETHON:         performed EASY url= response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.424153
** [hidemyass] http://24.38.63.26:80 : 200
ETHON:         performed EASY url= response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=1.645974
** [hidemyass] http://207.5.112.114:8080 : 200
ETHON:         performed EASY url= response_code=0
....

Comment: 'gem list hidemyass' shows *** LOCAL GEMS *** hidemyass (0.0.9). I did not do anything different, could you elaborate on any additional steps you took to acheive this.

Comment: I just followed github example and steps mentioned there.... I used ruby 1.9.2 series and rails 3.2....

Comment: Using rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0, does it mean this is the issue?

Comment: No, this can not be an issue.... I just tested this using 'hidemyass' gem on a sample rails 4.0.2 app running on ruby-2.0.0-p247 and got same loggers as in first comment on console and response object looked like #<Typhoeus::Response:0x9a883ac @options={:httpauth_avail=>0, :total_time=>1.668989, :starttransfer_time=>1.515321,.....